AWS Transfer Server is unable to verify access to API
I am using Pulumi to build an SFTP server with authentication via API Gateway and a Lambda function. For some reason, the transfer server is unable to verify access to the API gateway. I receieve the following error on pulumi up:

error: 1 error occurred:
creating Transfer Server: InvalidRequestException: Unable to verify access to API {URL}

Here is the relevant Pulumi code. The problem is likely with sftpServerPolicy and sftpServer (at the bottom).
// Create an S3 bucket to store files accessible via SFTP
const sftpBucket = new aws.s3.Bucket(`${config.prefix}-testSftp-bucket`, {
  acl: "private",
  tags: config.tags,
});

// Create a secret for the SFTP login
const sftpSecret = new aws.secretsmanager.Secret(`${config.prefix}-testSftp-secret`, {
  tags: config.tags,
});

// Define the IAM role and policy that allows the Lambda function to access S3 resources
const authLambdaRole = new aws.iam.Role(`${config.prefix}-testSftpAuth-lambda-role`, {
  assumeRolePolicy: aws.iam.assumeRolePolicyForPrincipal({ Service: "lambda.amazonaws.com" }),
});

const authLambdaSecretsPolicy = new aws.iam.RolePolicy(`${config.prefix}-testSftpAuth-lambdaSecretsPolicy`, {
  role: authLambdaRole.id,
  policy: sftpSecret.arn.apply(sftpSecretArn => JSON.stringify({
    Version: "2012-10-17",
    Statement: [{
      Action: ["secretsmanager:GetSecretValue"],
      Effect: "Allow",
      Resource: sftpSecretArn,
    }],
  })),
});

// Zip auth Lambda source and dependencies
const authLambdaDir = "../functions/testSftpAuth";
const authLambdaZipPath = `${authLambdaDir}/testSftpAuth.zip`;
packageLambda(authLambdaDir, authLambdaZipPath);

// Create a Lambda to authenticate SFTP logins
const authLambda = new aws.lambda.Function(`${config.prefix}-testSftpAuth`, {
  code: new pulumi.asset.AssetArchive({
    ".": new pulumi.asset.FileArchive(authLambdaZipPath)
  }),
  role: authLambdaRole.arn,
  handler: "function.handler",
  runtime: aws.lambda.Runtime.Python3d12,
  environment: {
    variables: {
      SECRET_ARN: sftpSecret.arn
    },
  },
  tags: config.tags,
});

// Create an API gateway for auth Lambda
const authApi = new aws.apigatewayv2.Api(`${config.prefix}-testSftpAuth-api`, {
  protocolType: "HTTP",
  tags: config.tags,
});

// Associate the API gateway with the Lambda
const authApiIntegration = new aws.apigatewayv2.Integration(`${config.prefix}-testSftpAuth-integration`, {
  apiId: authApi.id,
  integrationType: "AWS_PROXY",
  integrationUri: authLambda.arn,
});

// Create a route for the auth API
const authApiRoute = new aws.apigatewayv2.Route(`${config.prefix}-testSftpAuth-route`, {
  apiId: authApi.id,
  routeKey: "POST /auth",
  target: authApiIntegration.id.apply(authApiIntegrationId => `integrations/${authApiIntegrationId}`),
});

// Create a stage for the auth API
const authApiStage = new aws.apigatewayv2.Stage(`${config.prefix}-testSftpAuth-stage`, {
  apiId: authApi.id,
  autoDeploy: true,
  tags: config.tags,
});

// Create IAM role and policy for the SFTP server to access S3
const sftpRole = new aws.iam.Role(`${config.prefix}-testSftp-role`, {
  assumeRolePolicy: aws.iam.assumeRolePolicyForPrincipal({ Service: "transfer.amazonaws.com" }),
});

const sftpServerPolicy = new aws.iam.RolePolicy(`${config.prefix}-testSftp-policy`, {
  role: sftpRole.id,
  policy: pulumi.all([authApiStage.executionArn, sftpBucket.arn]).apply(([authApiStageExecutionArn, sftpBucketArn]) =>
    JSON.stringify({
      Version: "2012-10-17",
      Statement: [
        {
          Action: ["s3:ListBucket", "s3:GetObject", "s3:PutObject", "s3:DeleteObject"],
          Effect: "Allow",
          Resource: `${sftpBucketArn}/*`,
        },
        {
          Action: ["execute-api:Invoke"],
          Effect: "Allow",
          Resource: `${authApiStageExecutionArn}/POST/auth`
        }
      ],
    })
  )
});

const sftpServer = new aws.transfer.Server(`${config.prefix}-testSftp-server`, {
  endpointType: "PUBLIC",
  identityProviderType: "API_GATEWAY",
  invocationRole: sftpRole.arn,
  url: authApiStage.invokeUrl.apply(invokeUrl => `${invokeUrl}/auth`),
  loggingRole: sftpRole.arn,
});

